# jquery-ui autocomplete selecting the only answer

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to have jquery-ui autocomplete automatically select the answer if there is only one answer that comes back.

Comment: I'm posting this (and a few others) because I found an answer, but I'm curious if anybody has a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I set up the autocomplete with an "open" callback:

```
    $('#people_new_user input[type="text"]').each(
    function(index, element) {
        var field = element.name;
        $(element)
            .autocomplete({
          source: "/cf/AutoComplete/People?current="+field,
          open: openUser
        });
    });
```

And in the open callback I look to see if there is only one result, and select it if it is:

```
function openUser(event, ui)
{
  // Try to select the first one if it's the only one
  var $children = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete').menu.element.children();
  if ($children.size() == 1)
  {
     $children.first().click();
  }
}
```

Comment: For what sign `$` before `children` variable?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko it's a convention to put a $ in front of your variable name if it holds a jQuery object.

Comment: I got this `.data` is undefined.

Comment: @JPHellemons are you using a current version of jQuery?

Comment: @PaulTomblin yes, but it works now: `response: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.content.length === 1) {
                        $("#tbSSearch").val(ui.content[0].value);
                        $("#ibSearch").click();
                    }
                }`

Comment: Same problem for me, I can't get data('autocomplete'). `Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined`

Comment: I Got it : It is ui-autocomplete, not just autocomplete. And the children are li, not a

Comment: I had to put this : 
     var $children = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete').menu.element.children();
      if ($children.size() == 1)
      {
       $children.first().click();
      }

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this, it works well for us. In case it helps anyone, I had problems with it when first using it under IE10.
It had always worked fine in IE8, Chrome and Firefox.

Under IE10 it failed on the `jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.element.children()` line with: *Member not found*

This turned out to be simply because the web page had: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>`
Removing this fixed the problem (and it still works fine in IE8).

But before I noticed this I spent a lot of time trying and failing to move to jquery-1.11.1.min.js (from 1.6.4) and jquery-ui-1.11.0 (from 1.8.16).